# Is Posible create local genexus Java Environment with Remote Mysql?

Tags: genexus

Is Posible create local genexus Java Environment with not localhost mysql ( Remote Mysql ) ?
is GAM Working for this configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But with a GeneXus fully licensed. You can't use GeneXus Trial for this scenario.
See this documentation: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30900,GeneXus+16+hardware+and+software+requirements#Supported+DBMSes